# Does the Intel Neural Compute Stick 2 improve OpenCV2 performance on raspberry pi 4

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi4

I'm currently working on a project where it requires me to use opencv2 functions like StereoBM and filtering. is it somehow possible to use a NCS2 to accelerate the python program to make it faster? or is there an alternative hardware accelerator or microprocessor?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: although the intel myriad devices are VPUs, they can currently only be used for deep neiral network inference within opencv, afaik. However see https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/Is-there-API-doc-or-C-samples-to-process-Stereo-cameras-on/m-p/1131608

Comment: one chance: You could try using the myriad as an opencl device and use opencv with opencl support: https://techdecoded.intel.io/quickhits/accelerate-graphics-with-opencl-in-the-openvino-toolkit/#gs.2p91f2

Comment: Thank you, will look at the links that are provided